# How to fix error in File Upload Custom Options Product?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, simple-product, image-upload, upload

I have this error after try to upload a image in simple product on **Magento 1.9.2.3**. This option is a **custom option** inserted in simple product. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the custom option from required.